# mongoose sort, limit and then distinct

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a model `Model` in mongoose, 
where there are 3 fields.
`data`, `main_id` and `sub_id`

So if I do `Model.find()`:

I get something like below

```
[
 {data: 5, main_id: A, sub_id: X, created: 5/4/2020}, 
 {data: 6, main_id: A, sub_id: Y, created: 5/4/2020}, 
 {data: 7, main_id: B: sub_id: M, created: 4/4/2020}, 
 {data:11, main_id: A, sub_id: X, created: 3/4/2020}, 
 {data:12, main_id: A, sub_id: Y, created: 4/4/2020}, 
 {data:13, main_id: A, sub_id: X, created: 4/4/2020}
]
```

I want to get all the `data` field that is unique to `main_id: A` sorted by `created` and `limit` to `1`  for each `sub_id` under the `main_id`

So, in this case, I want to have a returned array of `[5, 6]` because that is the latest `data` entry for `main_id: A` and latest for `sub_id: X` and `Y` which are under `main_id: A` respectively.

Comment: Did you try aggregation with $group?

Comment: No, I don't have a clear cut idea about how to do that

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregations stages.

```js
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "main_id": "A"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "created": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {sub_id: "$sub_id"},
      data: {
        "$first": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fWid8IsCCos)

The result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Y",
    "data": 6
  },
  {
    "_id": "X",
    "data": 5
  }
]
```

Note that .aggregate() method always returns objects, so in express application you can do a simply map to transform it to `[5, 6]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am getting an sub_id must be an accumulator object error

Comment: @KevinRED, mongodb aggreagation returns object like this,  you can easily convert this to [5,6] in your app after you get response fro mongodb.

Comment: I didn't get it,

Comment: @KevinRED are you trying my aggregation code? As you see it works in the playground.

Comment: It works with a small change, now it is okay, thanks very much